# Harmonic Functions and Harmonic Conjugates on an Annular Domain

Tags: complex-analysis

At a recent study session my professor and peers gave an intuitive set-map illustration of how a harmonic function on a domain $D$ has a harmonic conjugate function on $D$ (see below).

[image: whiteboard]

The problem was posed thusly:

"Let $D = \{a \lt |z| \lt b \}$ \ $(-b , -a)$, an annulus slit along the negative real axis. [Demonstrate] that any harmonic function on $D$ has a harmonic conjugate on $D$." - Gamelin

In the image above

$\hspace{2in}$ $u: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (annulus to reals)
$\hspace{2in}$ $f: A \rightarrow S$ (annulus to rectangle)
$\hspace{2in}$ $\tilde{u}: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (rectangle to reals)
$\hspace{2in}$ $\tilde{v}: S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (rectangle to reals)
$\hspace{2in}$ $v: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (annulus to reals),

where the "~" denotes complex conjugacy. What I'd like to understand is how these data can be used to piece together the existence of a harmonic conjugate within $D$.

> $2.5 .3\quad$ Composition of harmonic functions
> Corollary.
>
> If $u: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic and $g: \tilde{D} \rightarrow D$ is differentiable, then $u \circ g: \tilde{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is harmonic.
>
> **Proof** Write $u=\operatorname{Re}(f),$ where $f$ is differentiable. Then $u \circ g=\operatorname{Re}(f \circ g)$ and $f \circ g$ is differentiable, so $\Delta(u \circ g)=0$

Comment: Is this the purdue math club?

Comment: You mean the image? No, this is not the Purdue Math Club.

Comment: Ok, sorry it just looked a lot like it haha.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: OK, so for example, if $f =$ Log$(z)$, whose inverse is $f^{-1} = e^z$, then because $f^{-1}$ is differentiable which then means $u \circ f^{-1}$ is harmonic (see 2.5.3 above), then $u$ has a harmonic conjugate on $D$, correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conformal maps preserve harmonicity, i.e. if $f$ is a one-to-one conformal map from $A$ onto $S$, then $u$ is a harmonic function on $A$ if and only if $u \circ f^{-1}$ is harmonic on $S$.  If you already know that a harmonic function on $S$ has a harmonic conjugate, say $w$, then $w \circ f$ is a harmonic function on $A$, and this will be the harmonic conjugate of $u$.